# i am getting attribute error while running erc20 brownie project on rinkeby testnet

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, rinkeby, brownie, solidity-0.8.x

PS E:\ERC20-BROWNIE> brownie run scripts/1_deploy_token.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Erc20BrownieProject is the active project.

File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File ".\scripts\1_deploy_token.py", line 12, in main
my_token = MyToken.deploy(initial_supply, {"from": account})
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 595, in **call**
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
PS E:\ERC20-BROWNIE> brownie run scripts/1_deploy_token.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Erc20BrownieProject is the active project.

File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File ".\scripts\1_deploy_token.py", line 12, in main
my_token = MyToken.deploy(initial_supply, {"from": account})
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 595, in **call**
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
PS E:\ERC20-BROWNIE> brownie run scripts/1_deploy_token.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Erc20BrownieProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\1_deploy_token.py::main'...
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File ".\scripts\1_deploy_token.py", line 12, in main
my_token = MyToken.deploy(initial_supply, {"from": account})
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 595, in **call**
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
PS E:\ERC20-BROWNIE>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify get_account() function like this, then it works.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

here is another solution: you can leave your get_account() as is. instead of commenting out the two lines like Ganesh's solution, you can add the rinkeby network in your yaml file.

This is because `if network.show_active() in config["networks"]:` is looking for "networks" in your brownie-config.yaml file.

if you add the rinkeby network there with some property, it will work.

for example,

```
networks:
  rinkeby:
    verify: True
```

my brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0"
dotenv: .env
networks:
  rinkeby:
    verify: True
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post your source code and the main error, not the whole console output without source code.
That being said, the error:

> AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction
> parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the sender of the
> transaction

is received when you are making a transaction without specifying the last dictionary argument which must contain the "from" field. Every transaction must have it.

```
SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account}) # it's ok
SimpleStorage.deploy() # will fail with above error
```